# External python modules in youcompletme

Tags: python, vim

I'm using YouCompletMe in Vim for python development.

Can I somehow specify an arbitrary path in the system where a module is located that I want to be included in the completion?
Or does it have to be ctags?

Comment: `ctags` isn't used for completion - `Jedi` is by default. Pretty much the best you'll find. Are you sure you're not using the wrong _kind_ of completion? Vim has its own internal engine, there's tag completion, omnicompletion (what `Jedi` does with YCM AFAIK) and various other terms describing sometimes the same or different things. There's also multiple way to activate it. YCM uses `<C-Space>` IIRC, there's `<Tab>` and `<C-P>`. Also, IIRC, the details on how to change the engine was on the [github page](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) or the github wiki for YCM.

Comment: Well, the completion for python standard module works. For instance math, I can import math and type math. and it shows me the possibilities. I'd like that for modules that aren't shipped with python.

Comment: I think `Jedi` does that, not sure but, that's why I'm saying you should check it out. I recall that other such tools like `Tern` or clang completion _do_ check other files to improve completion. For javascript there's a vim syntax file for common libraries, maybe something like that exists for python, but I haven't checked (and this will probably have no effect at all).